# Syntactical analyzer from regex

Tags: regex, parsing, syntax, grammar, analysis

I need to build parsing try / analyser from this:

```
x (x | "x+y")* x+ y
```

For now I have grammar:

```
S -> x A x B y
A -> x A
A -> x+y A
A -> epsilon
B -> x B
B -> epsilon
```

And code like so:

```
S() {
    if (token == 'x') {
        A();
        if (token == 'x') {
            B();
            if (token == 'y') {
                // success
            } else {
                // syntax err
            }
        } else {
            // syntax err
        }
    } else {
        // syntax err
    }
}

A() {
    if (token == 'x') {
        if (token == '+') {
            if (token == 'y') {
                A();
            } else {
                // syntax err
            }
        } else {
            A();
        }
    } else { 
        // epsilon 
    }
}

B() {
    if (token == 'x') {
        B();
    } else { 
        // epsilon 
    }
}
```

The problem is `B()` from main `S()` function never be called cuz `A()` function gets all `x` tokens because of `(x | "x+y")*` cycle. For example:
`xxxxx+yx+yx+yxxxxxy`
How can I solve my problem and parse it? 
What Im doing wrong?

p.s. sorry for english, tnx for attention

Comment: Your regex `x (x | "x+y")* x+ y` is equivelent to the regex `x (x | "x+y")* x y` because every x other than the last can be eaten by the kleene star.

Comment: It is, but problem still exists, `A()` function gets all of 'x' tokens and when executes`if (token == 'x') ... ` expression would be false

Answer (score 0):

I guess solution is in this grammar:

```
S -> x A
A -> x A
A -> x+y A
A -> xy
```

So on, the problem disappears